# Count of Files Under a Folder in a Document Library

Tags: document-library, folder

Is there a way to get a count of the files under a folder in a SharePoint 2010 (enterprise) document library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help - [Gathering item count for all document libraries in a Site Collection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2012/01/20/sharepoint-powershell-script-series-part-4-gathering-item-count-for-all-document-libraries-in-a-site-collection.aspx) (PowerShell script with some tweaking needed).

Comment: Blog has moved, but I believe [this](https://blog.russmax.com/sharepoint-powershell-script-series-part-4gathering-item-count-for-all-document-libraries-in-a-site-collection/) is an updated correct link.

Answer (score 2):

This works perfect for me `$list.Items.Count` in the following script:

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://dev.company.com/"

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{
    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        foreach ($SPWeb in $SPSite.AllWebs)
        {
            foreach ($list in $SPWeb.Lists)
            {
                if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary")
                {
                    $ListURL = $SPWeb.url + "/" + $list.RootFolder.Url
                    Write-Host $ListURL
                    Write-Host "  No of item: " $list.Items.Count

                    if ($SPWeb -ne $null)
                    {
                        $SPWeb.Dispose()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        $SPSite.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilecollection.count.aspx

```
SPFolder.Files.Count
```

is what you are looking for I believe.

Answer (score 1):

[SPFolder.ItemCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.itemcount.aspx) will give you the number of items in the folder, but this is both files and subfolder and only direct children

If you only need the file count then the `SPFolder.ItemCount - SPFolder.SubFolders.Count` may be faster than `SPFolder.Files.Count` if there are a lot more files than folders and you're not going to use the `SPFile` objects for anything.

To get all files regardless of level you may loop through subfolders recursively.

Comment: Note that `SPFolder.ItemCount` is not available in SP 2007.